# adding empty c++ file to xcode project creates syntax errors in obj-c header file

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working on adding code to an existing iphone app (written by someone else) that uses the card.io project. This is the first change i've attempted. The app compiles and runs fine with no changes but then when I try to add an empty .cpp and .h file to my xcode project I start getting syntax errors in an unrelated obj-c header file called CardIOMacros.h. I am using xcode 7.2 and compiling for an iphone 4s device.

The process I went through to add the .cpp and .h file was

1. right click on the project node in the project navigator
2. click new file
3. click c++ icon
4. type name of file and check create header file option
5. Select the subdirectory within my project directory.
6. press the build and run button in the main menu

Below is the file where I am getting errors. The errors are shown below the code.

```
//
//  CardIOMacros.h
//  See the file "LICENSE.md" for the full license governing this code.
//

// CardIOLog is a replacement for NSLog that logs iff CARDIO_DEBUG is set.

#if CARDIO_DEBUG
#define CardIOLog(format, args...) NSLog(format, ## args)
#else
#define CardIOLog(format, args...)
#endif

@interface CardIOMacros : NSObject

+ (id)localSettingForKey:(NSString *)key defaultValue:(NSString *)defaultValue productionValue:(NSString *)productionValue;

+ (NSUInteger)deviceSystemMajorVersion; 

+ (BOOL)appHasViewControllerBasedStatusBar; 

@end

#define iOS_MAJOR_VERSION  [CardIOMacros deviceSystemMajorVersion]
#define iOS_8_PLUS         (iOS_MAJOR_VERSION >= 8)
#define iOS_7_PLUS         (iOS_MAJOR_VERSION >= 7)
#define iOS_6              (iOS_MAJOR_VERSION == 6)
#define iOS_5              (iOS_MAJOR_VERSION == 5)
```

Compliler Errors

```
/Users/michael/sdev/projectname/ios/card.io-iOS-20151210/Classes/CardIOMacros.h
/Users/michael/sdev/projectname/ios/card.io-iOS-20151210/Classes/CardIOMacros.h:14:1: Expected unqualified-id
/Users/michael/sdev/projectname/ios/card.io-iOS-20151210/Classes/CardIOMacros.h:18:1: Expected external declaration
/Users/michael/sdev/projectname/ios/card.io-iOS-20151210/Classes/CardIOMacros.h:18:4: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
/Users/michael/sdev/projectname/ios/card.io-iOS-20151210/Classes/CardIOMacros.h:18:15: Expected ';' after top level declarator
/Users/michael/sdev/projectname/ios/card.io-iOS-20151210/Classes/CardIOMacros.h:20:1: Expected external declaration
/Users/michael/sdev/projectname/ios/card.io-iOS-20151210/Classes/CardIOMacros.h:20:4: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
/Users/michael/sdev/projectname/ios/card.io-iOS-20151210/Classes/CardIOMacros.h:20:9: Expected ';' after top level declarator
/Users/michael/sdev/projectname/ios/card.io-iOS-20151210/Classes/CardIOMacros.h:22:1: Expected unqualified-id
```

The .h and .cpp file are empty and I dont even #include the new c++ header file in any other file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have said header included in `...-Prefix.pch`.

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: Xcode projects usually have a `PROJECT_NAME-Prefix.pch` file under the "Supporting files" group. The compiler behaves as if this file was included in each source file. So if you have Objective-C code in this prefix header (or include a file containing Objective-C) even an empty cpp would fail to compile, because Xcode would try to build the Objective-C code from the prefix header with its C++ compiler.

Comment: That was it. There was "#import CardIOMacros.h" in one of the -Prefix.pch files. I wrapped it in "#ifdef __OBJC__  #endif" macro and it works! Thank you, you are awesome!